# jQuery search replace string

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to rename some fields in a clone function, but I'm not sure how to rename (increase) the field name.

```
var tr = $copy.clone();
tr('input').each(function() {
  console.log(this.name); 
  this.name = something;
});
```

**Example of field name:**

```
field[subform][0][subsubform][2][name]
```

In this case I would need to increase `[2]` to `[3]`. The name could have more or less brackets, but it's always the second last one that I would need to increase.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Store that number in a `data-` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to set it as a data-attribute because I'm using a complex form framework. It would have been a good and easy solution tho.

Comment: How would we know not to increase `[0]` to `[1]`? Please show us the function in context of your form framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression fun. Matches a pattern [number][string]end Of line, reads the number, adds one, joins other part of match, and sets the new name.

```
$(tr).find("input").prop("name", function() {
    return this.name.replace(
        /\[(\d+)(\]\[[^[]+]$)/,
        function (a,b,c) { 
            return "[" + (parseInt(b,10)+1) + "]" +  c;
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it will always precede a `[...]` at the end of the string:

```
name.replace(/\[(\d+)\](\[[^\[]+\])$/, function (pattern, value, tail) {
    return "[" + (parseInt(value, 10) + 1) + "]" + tail;
});​
```

Comment: This wouldnt work if there was suddenly more brackets to start with?

Comment: @charliexx If your pattern is going to change, then that would require a more flexible solution. I've updated my answer to contain a regular expression instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if it is always the second last one

```
var name = 'field[subform][0][subsubform][2][name]';
var firstStr = name.split('][').slice(0,-2);
var secStr = name.split('][').slice(-2);
secStr[0] = +secStr[0] +1; 
console.log(firstStr.concat(secStr).join(']['));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3TuHg/

or like this

```
var name = 'field[subform][0][subsubform][2][name]';
var str = name.split('][');
str[str.length - 2] = +str[str.length - 2] + 1;
str = str.join('][');
console.log(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NsGvv/

Answer (score 0):

Using `indexOf` and `substr`.

The following code gets the first part of the string before the number, the number, and the string after the number. Then add 1 to the number and concat everything.

```
var string = "field[subform][0][subsubform][2][name]",
    beg = string.indexOf("subsubform][") + 12,
    end = string.indexOf("]", beg);
string = string.substr(0, beg) + (parseInt(string.substr(beg, end)) + 1) + string.substr(end);
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qGMfS/)